# How to sort array that contain dictionaries of key value pair with string length

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

My array of dictionaries is:

```
 array==(
    {
    businessid = 9;
    keywordid = 127;
    keywordname = boutique;
},
    {
    businessid = 9;
    keywordid = 129;
    keywordname = clothing;
},
    {
    businessid = 9;
    keywordid = 138;
    keywordname = collection;
},
    {
    businessid = 9;
    keywordid = 143;
    keywordname = couture;
},
    {
    businessid = 9;
    keywordid = 131;
    keywordname = design;
},
    {
    businessid = 9;
    keywordid = 130;
    keywordname = designer;
},
    {
    businessid = 9;
    keywordid = 126;
    keywordname = fashion;
},
    {
    businessid = 9;
    keywordid = 144;
    keywordname = gown;
},
    {
    businessid = 9;
    keywordid = 137;
    keywordname = indian;
},
    {
    businessid = 9;
    keywordid = 141;
    keywordname = "kids wear";
},
    {
    businessid = 9;
    keywordid = 128;
    keywordname = "ladies clothes";
},
    {
    businessid = 9;
    keywordid = 142;
    keywordname = lehenga;
},
    {
    businessid = 9;
    keywordid = 139;
    keywordname = menswear;
},
    {
    businessid = 9;
    keywordid = 136;
    keywordname = salwar;
},
    {
    businessid = 9;
    keywordid = 132;
    keywordname = saree;
},
    {
    businessid = 9;
    keywordid = 133;
    keywordname = suit;
},
    {
    businessid = 9;
    keywordid = 135;
    keywordname = wedding;
},
    {
    businessid = 9;
    keywordid = 140;
    keywordname = "western wear";
}
```

)

I want to sort this array with its values length that is hold by key  "keywordname".

Please provide me relevant solution or any suggestion I am stukking here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks Its Working For me.

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
NSMutableArray * BusinessIdArray = [yourDictionary valueForKey:@"businessid"]; //it will put all the data of "businessid" into a single array
    NSLog(@"BusinessIdArray ===== %@", BusinessIdArray);

NSMutableArray * KeyWordIdArray = [yourDictionary valueForKey:@"keywordid"]; //it will put all the data of "keywordid" into a single array
    NSLog(@"KeyWordIdArray ===== %@", KeyWordIdArray);

NSMutableArray * KeywordnameArray = [yourDictionary valueForKey:@"keywordname"]; //it will put all the data of "keywordname" into a single array
    NSLog(@"KeywordnameArray ===== %@", KeywordnameArray);
```

To Combine all three array you can use the following code

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[newArray addObjectsFromArray: BusinessIdArray];

[newArray addObjectsFromArray: KeyWordIdArray];

[newArray addObjectsFromArray: KeywordnameArray];

NSLog(@"New Array after Combining all three arrays is %@",newArray);
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: sorry i need the sorted array with all 3 key value pairs containing by dictionary.

Comment: no issue you can make 3 arrays for all 3 key value pairs

Comment: then how can we map these three array into single array with its related id's.

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: Sorry  @Abhinandan  my problem is sort outed by comparator.

Comment: Thank u for your support.